# Ionic side menu template: modal login form not working

Tags: intel-xdk, ionic-framework

I grabbed the Ionic side menu starter template from Github. I created a fresh project in IntelXDK and copied the side menu code in. The app is working. The side menus look and works fine. It runs fine except for the Login menu. The modal shows, you can see the two form fields, but then nothing happens from there. You cannot click in either input field. You cannot click the submit button. You cannot click any menu button either. It appears to freeze.

This is just the default template code. Nothing else. I'm running in the IntelXDK emulator and/or my connected Android phone, same behavior on both.

What's happening? :-/